# ChatBot in TensorFlow: TypeError

Tags: python, tensorflow, chatbot, seq2seq

I'm trying to train a seq2seq model using a miniconda3 environment to create a chatbot. Below is the code I'm using to train it but I keep getting a TypeError when I get to this line of code:

```
training_predictions,test_predictions = seq2seq_model(tf.reverse(inputs, [-1]),
                                                      targets,
                                                      keep_prob,
                                                      batch_size,
                                                      sequence_length,
                                                      len(answerswords2int),
                                                      len(questionswords2int),
                                                      encoding_embedding_size,
                                                      decoding_embedding_size,
                                                      rnn_size,
                                                      num_layers,
                                                      questionswords2int)
```

[image]

I see that the error is prompted when the compiler gets to `tf.reverse(inputs, [-1])`. It's interpreting the second argument, which is [-1], as a list object when it's supposed to be a bool. I'm using a really common chatbot structure off of GitHub - [here](https://github.com/Achronus/Machine-Learning-101/blob/master/coding_templates_and_data_files/natural_language_processing/chatbot.py).

I have no idea why this is happening, can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: can you specify which Tensorflow version you are using, along with that can you also provide the shape of input and few sample input data.Thank you.